# Peewee and Flask-admin: I cannot display field from referenced table in admin view

Tags: flask, peewee, flask-admin

I cannot display selected field from referenced table. I am using peewee, Flask-admin and Flask-Security.

In Flask-admin view, value of foreign key field is displayed, but I need other field from referenced table (email).

My peewee model definitions:

```py
class User(BaseModel, UserMixin):
    """User of my app"""
    email = TextField(unique=True)
    password = TextField()


class UserDevice(BaseModel):
    """Table with all devices added and owned by users."""
    device_uniqueid = CharField(primary_key=True)
    device_user = ForeignKeyField(User, null=True, backref='userdevices')


class UserDeviceAdmin(ModelView):
    """Flask-admin view for managing devices"""
    column_list = ['device_uniqueid', 'device_user']
    column_sortable_list = ('device_uniqueid', ('device_user', User.email))
    form_ajax_refs = {'device_user': {'fields': (User.email, 'email')}}
```

I am geting this:
[flask-admin problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbjhW.png)

But I need not id of my user, but email...thanks

Comment: Glad you worked it out. I have only done this in SQLAlchemy, but the solution there is to use the backref as the column name, not the variable in the model class. Then you implement `__repr__` on the foreign class to display whatever you like. Using `form_ajax_refs` doesn't seem to be necessary usually.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```py
class UserDeviceAdmin(ModelView):
    """Flask-admin view for managing devices"""
    column_list = ['device_uniqueid', 'device_user.email']
    column_sortable_list = ('device_uniqueid', ('device_user', User.email))
    form_ajax_refs = {'device_user': {'fields': (User.email, 'email')}}
```